# Which tense to use in the following context?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> I **lived** in Mexico from 1990 to 2000.

Or

> I **had lived** in Mexico from 1990 to 2000.

Or

> I **have lived**  in Mexico from 1990 to 2000.

Which of these are grammatically correct?

Comment: Is there any context? Without any, there is no reason to use a perfect tense.

Comment: The reason I used the past perfect tense is because the action happened in the past and continued over a period of time, and finished over at a particular time in the past. I'd use the present perfect if it continues to the present.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are grammatically correct, **depending on context**. The third example, `I have lived in Mexico from 1990 to 2000,` likely would be a misuse of the continuous form, which implies the action is ongoing. Had you written, `I have lived in Mexico from 1990 to the present,` that, too, would be grammatically correct.

Comment: If meant that I lived temporarily in that period. Should I say, "I had been living in Mexico fron 1990 to 2000."??

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes. That would be fine. - DrMoishe Pippick